# How can I duplicate and translate a selection of edges constrained to the original mesh?

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, constraints

I have a rather large selection of edges on a subdivided plane. I would like to have duplicate edges right next to the original ones (on the same plane). In other words, each of the original edges should have a copy right next to it, with the distances between all pairs being equal. Is it possible to select all (original edges) duplicate them and translate them along the same face/plane? The only option I found the resembles it most, is just duplicating the edges, after which the duplicates are their own mesh floating around.

[image: Visualization]

In the above image, I want all the vertical lines to have a copy right next to it, as shown with the middle vertex. Is there a way to easily achieve this?

Comment: Might be helpful to add a few images of what you have/want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the mirror modifier or array modifier.  Also you can snap to increment so after you duplicate the edge its easy line up the edges the way you want.

Now that I see your picture you can just subdivide again.  Select the entire top and bottom edge in your image and subdivide again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I subdivide again, new edges will be places right in between the middle ones. But what if I want to have those extra edges right next to the original ones (i.e. move the new edges to the right/left)? That means the spacing between edges isn't equal. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: From there you can one of your edges then go to select -> select edge rings.  Next go to select -> checker deselect to highlight every other edge and then use the 3d cursor to move then edges into whatever position you want.

Comment: How do I use the 3D cursor to move edges?

Comment: Just select what you want to move and drag, in this case, the red arrow.

You also might be interested in these tutorials by BornCg.  It goes over the basics of blender including the 3d Cursor. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&index=1&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS